# wysiwyg editor don´t export paragraph <p>

Tags: custom-post-types, metabox, editor, wysiwyg

I use [cmb](https://github.com/jaredatch/Custom-Metaboxes-and-Fields-for-WordPress) for my custom metaboxes.

What I´ve done:

```
'type'    => 'wysiwyg'
```

My WP-Backend: (HTML-Editor):

```
<h1>Headline</h1>
Paragraph
```

Browser-Source just looks like:

```
<h1>Headline</h1>
Paragraph
```

Without `<p>` tag.

=> When I do the same code into the standard WP-Editor it works fine with `<p>`.

How can I export the `<p>`, too?

Thanks
Ogni

Answer (score 2):

```
global $post;
$paragraph = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'be_paragraph', true );
echo wpautop( $paragraph );
```

or

```
echo apply_filters( 'the_content', $paragraph );
```

[SOURCE](https://github.com/jaredatch/Custom-Metaboxes-and-Fields-for-WordPress/issues/211)

Comment: What is that? An answer to your question? Please add some explanation.